# fadeIn into jQuery Template tmpl()

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I ended up using jquery templates and so far everything is working fine, but now I want to fadeIn a new object into my "template", I was trying this but it didn't work out:

```
$("#itemsTemplate").tmpl(responseText).prependTo( "#map_right_wrap_template" ).fadeIn();
```

Context: 
- responseText is a json object that was returned by a form submission

In other words I want to add (fadeIn) the new-returned element into the template in a very fashion way. As I said everything is working fine except for the fadeIn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the element is hidden before adding it to the DOM? You can use `.hide()` just before adding the element to the DOM to make sure it will start hidden, and then fade in:

```
$("#itemsTemplate").tmpl(responseText).hide().prependTo( "#map_right_wrap_template" ).fadeIn(500);
```